# HTTP request not working when done in code

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, node-promisify

I am making a request and everything is correct but the issue I have is I keep getting a 404 error. but if I copy the parameters and body with that same url to postman it returns a success. I do not know what I am doing wrong.

```
const promisify = require('util').promisify;
const { post, get, del } = require('request');

const postAsync = promisify(post);
post: async (url, payload) => {
        console.log('USER ID PAYLOAD',payload)

        return postAsync(url, {

            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json"
            },
            json: true,
            body: payload
        })

        .then(response => {
            console.log('USER ID StAtUS CODE', response.url, response.body)
            if (response.statusCode >= 400) throw new Error(response.body.message || "An error occurred");
            if (response.body && response.body.status === 'error' || response.body.status === 'fail') throw new Error(response.body.message || "An error occurred");
            return response.body;
        }, error => {
            throw error;
        })
    },
```

Comment: maybe something to do with the `url` - since a 404 means "not found", the url must be wrong (unless the server is sending the wrong error code of course)

Comment: I logged the URL and it was correct, I equally copied the url and ran directly in post man, it worked

Comment: but 404 means Not Found, so something is wrong with it - is the server yours?

Comment: yes. That is what I am struggling to figure out. I logged in all the appropriate places and everything seems fine

Comment: Why do you use `async` for your post function if you're still doing callbacks inside of it?

Comment: what do you suggest @Clarity

Comment: add `resolveWithFullResponse: true` with the payload i.e. `{headers:{}, body: {}, resolveWithFullResponse: true}`, and then confirm the complete response you get.

Comment: Your code is A-OK. I just copied and ran it against a POST API of my own. Something weird seems to be up from where you are or the manner in which you are running the application